# I'm facing issue in custom post type like if there's no post then we have to show custom message like sorry no post available

Tags: wordpress, backend

I'm facing an issue with a custom post type where, if no posts are available, I need to display a custom message. I have tried the below code, but it is not working.

```
<div class="industry_item_grid">
        <div class="industry_item_head">
            <h3 class="industry_title">Telecom</h3>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url(
                "/category/telecom"
            ); ?>" class="casestudy_viewall">View all</a>
        </div>
        <div class="industry_item_row">
            <?php
            $paged = get_query_var("paged")
                ? get_query_var("paged")
                : 1;
            $args = [
                "post_type" => "post",
                "post_status" => "publish",
                "category_name" => "Telecom",
                "posts_per_page" => 3,
                "cat" => 23,
                "paged" => $paged,
            ];
            $arr_posts = new WP_Query($args);
            $totalpost = $arr_posts->found_posts;

            if ($arr_posts->have_posts()):
                while ($arr_posts->have_posts()):
                    $arr_posts->the_post(); ?>
                    //the_content();
            <?php
                endwhile;
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :

                        while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
                            $arr_posts->the_post();
```

You need to add a branch to your if statement for when `have_posts()` is false, like so:

```
if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
        $arr_posts->the_post();
?>
//the_content();
<?php
    endwhile;
else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, no posts available.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```